# passing options to a matplotlib backend in a clean way

Tags: matplotlib

For my personal use, several times I have modified the matplotlib gtk backend (also the tk and wx) , replacing the window with a notebook. This is because **I use too many plots at the same time**.

This time around I feel I can take the challenge to do a pull-request for my changes. But I want to do it as clean as possible. That is where I need advice (**clean** is the key).

I would like to place my class TabbedFigureManagerGTK3 inside 
[backend_gtk3.py](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3.py)

The problem is that using

```
matplotlib.use('gtk3cairo')
```

or

```
matplotlib.use('gtk3agg')
```

Directs the specified backend (gtk3cairo or gtk3agg) to use backend_gtk3.FigureManagerGTK3

I do not want to replicate [backend_gtk3agg.py](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3agg.py) and [backend_gtk3cairo.py](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3cairo.py) just to change the call to backend_gtk3.FigureManagerGTK3

I would like to implement a solution that allows the user to pass an option to the backend, and from there it choses the traditional FigureManagerGTK3 or my TabbedFigureManagerGTK3

I am looking for a recomendation on how to do it that has more chances to be accepted upstream (after pull-request and the whole shebang).

1. Do I modify matplotlib.use to add something like **kwargs?
2. Do I just recreate the whole [backend_gtk3agg.py](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3agg.py) and [backend_gtk3cairo.py](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3cairo.py) (subclassing of course)
3. Do I forget about trying to get this accepted and do it breaking the [Coding guide](http://matplotlib.org/devel/coding_guide.html)

Thanks
Federico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does sound like a nifty feature.

I would do it by modifying the existing manager and following how the `PySide` vs `PyQt` issue is handled (by using a secondary rcParams which controls which one the backend imports).  In your case, I would add `backend.gtk3.tabbed`, or something similarly named, which controls how the manager behaves.

Write your modifications so that changes as little of the existing api as possible (breaking backwards compatibility is a no-go) and make it so a user that doesn't explicitly enable your changes won't even know they are there.

Also email the dev list, they are all pretty friendly. Or just open a PR, that is the most effective way to get feed back.

Comment: Thanks, I did not think about rcparams, but it was the easiest way.

Comment: The first draft of the implementation is in https://github.com/fariza/matplotlib/tree/tabbed-gtk3-figuremanager